# JsPdf Table overflow Page

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am converting html table to pdf with jspdf. But when table is bigger than page, pdf looks like that;

[image: 1]

Any kind of suggestion accepted.

my js is:

```
function exportPDF(pdfName) {
    
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    var source = document.getElementById("tableForPdf");
console.log(source);
    var margins = {
        top: 30,
        bottom: 10,
        left: 80,
        width: 595
    };

    doc.fromHTML(
        source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left,
        margins.top, {
            'width': margins.width,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },

        function (dispose) {
            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            doc.save(pdfName+'.pdf');
        }, margins);
}
```

Comment: use [html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0) lib have auto page breaker